# F#, the value or constructor 'List' is not defined

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I am copying this code out of a book on F#. The compiler is supposed to create a generic function.

Instead, I am getting an error

"FS0039: The value or constructor 'List' is not defined."

Why?

```
let createList(first, second) = 
    let output = List()
    output.Add(first)
    output.Add(second)
    output

// expected output below
// val createList : first:'a * second:'a -> List<'a>
```

Answer (score 4):

I added this line to the script

```
open System.Collections.Generic
```

unlike C#, Visual Studio F# isn't good at telling you when you need to add an open statement like this.

Comment: Actually ionide in VSCode will suggest to open the System.Collections.Generic namespace. However this type of List usage in F# is not idiomatic and can be confusing. It's better to use `ResizeArray` which is a synonym for the C# List, and there is no need to open another namespace.

Comment: Visual Studio will also suggest this namespace, in addition to having a code fix that will add that line post-hoc if it is not defined.